# JavaScript, how to know if the url is a static file

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'm using express.js on a Node server and at the moment some GET request is for static file like ZZZ.html or YY.css ... I want to identify which url is for static file and which is a route.

How can I do that in my middleware?

(not sure if it's clear or not)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`fs`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback) module to determine if requested file exists.

In the simplest case your code might look like following:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  require('fs').stat(__dirname + req.url, function(err, stats) {
    var isFile = stats && stats.isFile();
    //do something with isFile variable
    next();
  });
});
```

Just put it before any other routes.

**Edit:** *doing this way you suppose that all your static files are located in the project's root dir. If your static files are in another dir (/public for example), you should write `__dirname + '/public' + req.url`, and check if `req.url` starts with `/public`.*

Comment: You'll still want to serve up a `public` directory though. Otherwise you may be exposing your `server.js` or other important files.

Comment: @Jordonias Yes, I know. That's why I wrote "In the simplest case". I should edit my answer though. Thanks :)

Comment: I assumed you knew. I wanted it to be clear for @WoofWoofDude

Comment: At the moment it's looking to work ! :) probably a temporary solution but it's working fine !

Answer (score 1):

Put your static files in a `public` directory and have

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

after your routes so it will catch other requests.

Comment: i'm not supposed to do that :/
Is there another solution ?

Comment: You could catch all unhandled routes with `app.get('*', function(req,res) {});` and check if the file exists and route it to a 404 page if not. But I don't recommend it. Why can't you use `express.static`?

Comment: Cause i'm new in the web dev-world (I began like 2 day ago!) and i'm working on a project where i'm not familiar with ..

want to keep this as simple as i can !

Comment: using `express.static` will be the simplest way. Anything else will be reinventing the wheel.

Comment: i can't put them in a public folder.. These file coming from my client folder.. a lot of .js/.html/.css ..

Comment: Ok. So you want to do something with these static files other than serve them?

Comment: I want to filter all routes and block some of them... like static files are okay.. but some url like "/student/:id" need the ":id" param.. if the user enter "/student/" then i need to redirect to an other url. Is that clear haha ?